# Django filter manytomany relation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm

I spent a lot of time trying to filter out the entities related many to many, but the result really amazes me. I can’t understand how to solve this and why this happens.

I have 2 models in Django:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    ...
    forms = models.ManyToManyField(Form, related_name='applications', through='ApplicationForm', blank=True)
    ...

class Form(models.Model):
    ...

class ApplicationForm(models.Model):
    application = models.ForeignKey(Application, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    form = models.ForeignKey(Form, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

In **ApplicationSerializer** I want to return filtered forms related to my application. I try to do this on this way:

```
forms = serializer.SerializerMethodField()

def get_forms(self, obj):
    qs = obj.forms.filter(status=Form.COMPLETED)
    return FormSerializer(qs, many=True, context=self.context).data
```

I have 2 forms and 3 applications which has both forms. But my function returns 6 forms [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2] for example.
I try to debug this and found that `obj.forms.all()` return 2 forms, but if I add filter it returns 6. I try to use `obj.forms.filter(status=Form.COMPLETED).distinct()` but result the same.

I can not create query like `Forms.objects.filter(status=Form.COMPLETED).filter(pk__in=...)` because i have many parameters prefetched and annotated on application manager level. So I want to know is there any way to filter manytomany relation objects related to my instance

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is only in showing data to user you can handle this 
in to_represnataion method. and modify data you wanna change.

```
    def to_representation(self, instance: Application):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        qs = obj.forms.filter(status=Form.COMPLETED)
        data['forms'] = FormSerializer(qs, many=True, context=self.context).data
        return data
```

Comment: No, I did not have problem with representation, main problem is that `obj.forms.filter(status=Form.COMPLETED)` return 4 instances instead of 2 for example